# How do I create an "add-on" package for my Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, package

I have a Laravel project that I have been building for a while now.  I want to add features that are not part of the main application, but can be added on as Add-In packages, but I don't know the best way to do this.  These packages will have their own routes, views, models, and controllers.

I have looked at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages and other sites for creating Laravel packages, but the big problem is that with this setup the package is loaded via composer.json.  Any time I update my main application and add a new dependency to the main project, it will overwrite the users composer.json with any add-in's they have registered.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have possibly two ways to create your own **add-on**

1. Use this package to create modules with your own stuff-
   https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules
2. Create your own package-
   https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/create-package-laravel/

Your doubts regarding developing the package and losing the changes, is not true. Please read the guide mentioned above and do more research on how to develop a package in Laravel.

Or you can choose the 1st option which is easier and less confusing where you can create your own module in a separate folder and use it in your application. You can also share it as a separate module.

> but the big problem is that with this setup the package is loaded via
>   composer.json. Any time I update my main application and add a new
>   dependency to the main project, it will overwrite the users
>   composer.json with any add-in's they have registered.

This is not true. You are confused about the overall use and functionality of composer.json.

When you create your own package/module, you have your own composer.json. You don't lose your changes if you add a new dependency or update your application.

Every time you add a new dependency or update your composer, your changes are updated on composer.json without wiping the existing package information. You don't have to worry about losing the changes.

Comment: Thank you for the help.